# Opencart product import image is not working

Tags: php, database, image, opencart, product

Hy all,

I'm working on an import of more than 30.000 products from an old webshop system to my OpenCart application.

I've got the categories working, and the products, but there is only 1 thing that i can't fix. That is that there's no image.

I've uploaded all images in `OpenCartRoot/image/data/old/tt_productsv2/images/`

In the database, it is inserted:
`image/old/tt_productsv2/images/greatest.jpg`

I've confirmed that that image exist, but when i check the front-end page, there are no images. Also when i check the back-end, i don't see any image linked to the product.

So my question is, what wrong I have done? Why isn't the image linked to the product, although i inserted the link in the database...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the image in the database should only be

```
old/tt_productsv2/images/greatest.jpg
```

as OpenCart will build the path like

```
DIR_IMAGE . 'old/tt_productsv2/images/greatest.jpg'
```

where `DIR_IMAGE` is defined like

```
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/path/to/web/root/image/');
```

Comment: You sir just made my day. That worked out absolutly perfect. If you've got an paypal account, then send me the details for a little reward. Because you saved me a hell of an headace :D

Comment: I do not do this for a reward - the best reward is to know I am helpful. I am glad I helped!

Comment: @shadyyx, i know, and i'm very very thankfull that you helped me. Have a realy nice day ;)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is a problem with GLOBAL_BRACE Constant.

Some servers do not support that constant value, so you can change the
server or change the code.

The code is in:

> admin / controller / common/ filemanager.php

line No : 37 ===================================================================

```html
<?php

class ControllerCommonFileManager extends Controller {

public function index() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {

$filter_name = rtrim(str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..', '*'), '', $this->request->get['filter_name']), '/');

} else {

$filter_name = null;

}



// Make sure we have the correct directory

if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');

} else {

$directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';

}



if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {

$page = $this->request->get['page'];

} else {

$page = 1;

}



$data['images'] = array();



$this->load->model('tool/image');



// Get directories

$directories = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);



if (!$directories) {

$directories = array();

}



// Get files

// $files = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE);



$files1 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.jpg');

if (!$files1) {

$files1 = array();

}



$files2 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.jpeg');

if (!$files2) {

$files2 = array();

}



$files3 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.JPG');

if (!$files3) {

$files3 = array();

}



$files4 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.png');

if (!$files4) {

$files4 = array();

}



$files5 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.JPEG');

if (!$files5) {

$files5 = array();

}



$files6 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.PNG');

if (!$files6) {

$files6 = array();

}



$files7 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.GIF');

if (!$files7) {

$files7 = array();

}

$files8 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.gif');

if (!$files8) {

$files8 = array();

}





$files = array_merge($files1, $files2,$files3,$files4,$files5,$files6,$files7,$files8);





// Merge directories and files

$images = array_merge($directories, $files);



// Get total number of files and directories

$image_total = count($images);



// Split the array based on current page number and max number of items per page of 10

$images = array_splice($images, ($page - 1) * 16, 16);



foreach ($images as $image) {

$name = str_split(basename($image), 14);



if (is_dir($image)) {

 $url = '';



 if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

     $url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

 }



 if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

     $url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

 }



 $data['images'][] = array(

     'thumb' => '',

     'name'  => implode(' ', $name),

     'type'  => 'directory',

     'path'  => utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)),

     'href'  => $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&directory=' . urlencode(utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/'))) . $url, true)

 );

} elseif (is_file($image)) {

 // Find which protocol to use to pass the full image link back

 if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {

     $server = HTTPS_CATALOG;

 } else {

     $server = HTTP_CATALOG;

 }



 $data['images'][] = array(

     'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize(utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)), 100, 100),

     'name'  => implode(' ', $name),

     'type'  => 'image',

     'path'  => utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)),

     'href'  => $server . 'image/' . utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE))

 );

}

}



$data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');



$data['text_no_results'] = $this->language->get('text_no_results');

$data['text_confirm'] = $this->language->get('text_confirm');



$data['entry_search'] = $this->language->get('entry_search');

$data['entry_folder'] = $this->language->get('entry_folder');



$data['button_parent'] = $this->language->get('button_parent');

$data['button_refresh'] = $this->language->get('button_refresh');

$data['button_upload'] = $this->language->get('button_upload');

$data['button_folder'] = $this->language->get('button_folder');

$data['button_delete'] = $this->language->get('button_delete');

$data['button_search'] = $this->language->get('button_search');



$data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$data['directory'] = urlencode($this->request->get['directory']);

} else {

$data['directory'] = '';

}



if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {

$data['filter_name'] = $this->request->get['filter_name'];

} else {

$data['filter_name'] = '';

}



// Return the target ID for the file manager to set the value

if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$data['target'] = $this->request->get['target'];

} else {

$data['target'] = '';

}



// Return the thumbnail for the file manager to show a thumbnail

if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$data['thumb'] = $this->request->get['thumb'];

} else {

$data['thumb'] = '';

}



// Parent

$url = '';



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$pos = strrpos($this->request->get['directory'], '/');



if ($pos) {

 $url .= '&directory=' . urlencode(substr($this->request->get['directory'], 0, $pos));

}

}



if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

}



if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

}



$data['parent'] = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true);



// Refresh

$url = '';



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$url .= '&directory=' . urlencode($this->request->get['directory']);

}



if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

}



if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

}



$data['refresh'] = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true);



$url = '';



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$url .= '&directory=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['directory'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

}



if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {

$url .= '&filter_name=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['filter_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

}



if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

}



if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

}



$pagination = new Pagination();

$pagination->total = $image_total;

$pagination->page = $page;

$pagination->limit = 16;

$pagination->url = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url . '&page={page}', true);



$data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();



$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/filemanager', $data));

}



public function upload() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



$json = array();



// Check user has permission

if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');

}



// Make sure we have the correct directory

if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');

} else {

$directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';

}



// Check its a directory

if (!is_dir($directory)) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_directory');

}



if (!$json) {

if (!empty($this->request->files['file']['name']) && is_file($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'])) {

 // Sanitize the filename

 $filename = basename(html_entity_decode($this->request->files['file']['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));



 // Validate the filename length

 if ((utf8_strlen($filename) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($filename) > 255)) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filename');

 }



 // Allowed file extension types

 $allowed = array(

     'jpg',

     'jpeg',

     'gif',

     'png'

 );



 if (!in_array(utf8_strtolower(utf8_substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1)), $allowed)) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filetype');

 }



 // Allowed file mime types

 $allowed = array(

     'image/jpeg',

     'image/pjpeg',

     'image/png',

     'image/x-png',

     'image/gif'

 );



 if (!in_array($this->request->files['file']['type'], $allowed)) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filetype');

 }



 // Return any upload error

 if ($this->request->files['file']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_upload_' . $this->request->files['file']['error']);

 }

} else {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_upload');

}

}



if (!$json) {

move_uploaded_file($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'], $directory . '/' . $filename);



$json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_uploaded');

}



$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');

$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

}



public function folder() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



$json = array();



// Check user has permission

if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');

}



// Make sure we have the correct directory

if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');

} else {

$directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';

}



// Check its a directory

if (!is_dir($directory)) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_directory');

}



if (!$json) {

// Sanitize the folder name

$folder = str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', basename(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['folder'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));



// Validate the filename length

if ((utf8_strlen($folder) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($folder) > 128)) {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_folder');

}



// Check if directory already exists or not

if (is_dir($directory . '/' . $folder)) {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_exists');

}

}



if (!$json) {

mkdir($directory . '/' . $folder, 0777);

chmod($directory . '/' . $folder, 0777);



$json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_directory');

}



$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');

$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

}



public function delete() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



$json = array();



// Check user has permission

if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');

}



if (isset($this->request->post['path'])) {

$paths = $this->request->post['path'];

} else {

$paths = array();

}



// Loop through each path to run validations

foreach ($paths as $path) {

$path = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $path), '/');



// Check path exsists

if ($path == DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog') {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_delete');



 break;

}

}



if (!$json) {

// Loop through each path

foreach ($paths as $path) {

 $path = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $path), '/');



 // If path is just a file delete it

 if (is_file($path)) {

     unlink($path);



 // If path is a directory beging deleting each file and sub folder

 } elseif (is_dir($path)) {

     $files = array();



     // Make path into an array

     $path = array($path . '*');



     // While the path array is still populated keep looping through

     while (count($path) != 0) {

         $next = array_shift($path);



         foreach (glob($next) as $file) {

             // If directory add to path array

             if (is_dir($file)) {

                 $path[] = $file . '/*';

             }



             // Add the file to the files to be deleted array

             $files[] = $file;

         }

     }



     // Reverse sort the file array

     rsort($files);



     foreach ($files as $file) {

         // If file just delete

         if (is_file($file)) {

             unlink($file);



         // If directory use the remove directory function

         } elseif (is_dir($file)) {

             rmdir($file);

         }

     }

 }

}



$json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_delete');

}



$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');

$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

}

}
```